# Minimum no. of comparisons to find median of 3 numbers

Tags: median

I was implementing quicksort and I wished to set the pivot to be the median or three numbers. The three numbers being the first element, the middle element, and the last element.

Could I possibly find the median in less no. of comparisons?

```
median(int a[], int p, int r)
{
    int m = (p+r)/2;
    if(a[p] < a[m])
    {
        if(a[p] >= a[r])
            return a[p];
        else if(a[m] < a[r])
            return a[m];
    }
    else
    {
        if(a[p] < a[r])
            return a[p];
        else if(a[m] >= a[r])
            return a[m];
    }
    return a[r];
}
```

Comment: Do you only care about number of comparisons? Is other arithmetic operation number not bounded?

Comment: I just want an efficient code to calculate the median.

Comment: Then you have it. Best case is 2 comparisons, worst case is 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it in one, and you're only using two or three, so I'd say you've got the minimum number of comparisons already.

Comment: can it be done in strictly 2 comparisons for any 3 numbers ?

Comment: No, you would have to have a tie breaker if, for instance, you picked the two minimum values. Though if you're willing to use other operations you can get away with two comparisons.  See Raghav's answer.

Comment: But I think that @Raghav's answer would be incorrect if any of them are equal or it doesn't consider many other cases

Answer (score 15):

If the concern is only comparisons, then this should be used.

```
int getMedian(int a, int b , int c) {
    int x = a-b;
    int y = b-c;
    int z = a-c;
    if(x*y > 0) return b;
    if(x*z > 0) return c;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Or using ternary operator (C, C#, Java, Javascript, ...) simply: `((a-b)*(b-c) > -1 ? b : ((a-b)*(a-c) < 1 ? a : c))`

Answer (score 7):

```
int32_t FindMedian(const int n1, const int n2, const int n3) {
    auto _min = min(n1, min(n2, n3));
    auto _max = max(n1, max(n2, n3));
    return (n1 + n2 + n3) - _min - _max;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than just computing the median, you might as well put them in place.  Then you can get away with just 3 comparisons all the time, and you've got your pivot closer to being in place.

```
T median(T a[], int low, int high)
{
    int middle = ( low + high ) / 2;
    if( a[ middle ].compareTo( a[ low ] ) < 0 )
        swap( a, low, middle );
    if( a[ high ].compareTo( a[ low ] ) < 0 )
        swap( a, low, high );
    if( a[ high ].compareTo( a[ middle ] ) < 0 )
        swap( a, middle, high );

    return a[middle];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old thread, but I had to solve exactly this problem on a microcontroller that has very little RAM and does not have a h/w multiplication unit (:)). In the end I found the following works well:

```
static char medianIndex[] = { 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1 };

signed short getMedian(const signed short num[])
{
    return num[medianIndex[(num[0] > num[1]) << 2 | (num[1] > num[2]) << 1 | (num[0] > num[2])]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not afraid to get your hands a little dirty with compiler intrinsics you can do it with exactly 0 branches.

The same question was discussed before on:
[Fastest way of finding the middle value of a triple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582356/fastest-way-of-finding-the-middle-value-of-a-triple)

Though, I have to add that in the context of naive implementation of quicksort, with a lot of elements, reducing the amount of branches when finding the median is not so important because the branch predictor will choke either way when you'll start tossing elements around the the pivot. More sophisticated implementations (which don't branch on the partition operation, and avoid WAW hazards) will benefit from this greatly.

Answer (score 2):

remove max and min value from total sum

```
int med3(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int tot_v = a + b + c ;
    int max_v = max(a, max(b, c));
    int min_v = min(a, min(b, c));
    return tot_v - max_v - min_v
}
```

Comment: Please, try to explain your answer, add some comments.

Comment: That's already an answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29242318/1816580

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a clever way to isolate the median element from three using a careful analysis of the 6 possible permutations (of low, median, high).  In python:

```
def med(a, start, mid, last):
    # put the median of a[start], a[mid], a[last] in the a[start] position
    SM = a[start] < a[mid]
    SL = a[start] < a[last]
    if SM != SL:
        return
    ML = a[mid] < a[last]
    m = mid if SM == ML else last
    a[start], a[m] = a[m], a[start]
```

Half the time you have two comparisons otherwise you have 3 (avg 2.5).  And you only swap the median element once when needed (2/3 of the time).

Full python quicksort using this at:

https://github.com/mckoss/labs/blob/master/qs.py

Comment: Actually, it's not 2.5, but 2.666.. since you have two comparisons only in a third of the cases (assuming all three values are randomly chosen according to the same distribution and the probability of doubling a value i 0, that's the probability that a[start] contains the median).

Answer (score 1):

You can write up all the permutations:

```
    1 0 2
    1 2 0
    0 1 2
    2 1 0
    0 2 1
    2 0 1
```

Then we want to find the position of the `1`. We could do this with two comparisons, if our first comparison could split out a group of equal positions, such as the first two lines.

The issue seems to be that the first two lines are different on any comparison we have available: `a<b`, `a<c`, `b<c`. Hence we have to fully identify the permutation, which requires 3 comparisons in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Bitwise XOR operator, the median of three numbers can be found.

```
def median(a,b,c):
    m = max(a,b,c)
    n = min(a,b,c)
    ans = m^n^a^b^c
    return ans
```