# Median of 3 Numbers: Without using Array or Sorting Concept

Tags: arrays, if-statement, numbers, median

How can I calculate the median of three given numbers without using any array. Can we do it by simple calculation or comparison?

What i have tried so far:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
void main() 
{ 
  int a[3],i,n=3; 
  float m;
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter the elements:\n"); 
     for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
     { 
        scanf("%d",&a[i]); 
     } 
     if(n%2==0) 
     { 
       m=(a[n-1/2]+(a[n/2]))/2; 
     } 
     else 
     { 
       m=a[n/2]; 
     } 
     printf("\nMedian is %f",m); 
     getch(); 
}
```

*Preferred Code Languages*: C, Java

Comment: I have done it using array. @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
clrscr();
int a[3],i,n=3;
float m;
printf("Enter the elements:\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
if(n%2==0)
{
m=(a[n-1/2]+(a[n/2]))/2;
}
else
{
m=a[n/2];
}
printf("\nMedian is %f",m);
getch();
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Median** is a number that is either halfway into the set or you can think of it as middlemost number in the set. so for finding it we will just do the comparisons like below

`median = Math.max(Math.min(a,b), Math.min(Math.max(a,b),c));`  
answer reffered from [Fastest way of finding the middle value of a triple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582356/fastest-way-of-finding-the-middle-value-of-a-triple/14676309#14676309)