# Calculating middle int out of 3 ints

Tags: java, math

Is this *one-liner* correct for calculating the middle int between a, b and c?

> **Note:** *I don't want to calculate the mean, just the one that's in the middle if these 3 were ordered from smallest to
>   greatest (median).*

Example: the middle value of **1**, **77** and **34** is ***34***.

```
public static int midpoint(int a, int b, int c) {

    return a <= b ? (c <= a ? a : c <= b ? c : b ) : c <= b ? b : c <= a ? c : a;
}
```

Comment: so is your code working or not?

Comment: It is... but few tests were made...

Comment: I'm looking for a better solution (and correct in the case mine is wrong).

Comment: "Code works" == https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: If you are looking for a better solution than you must look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582356/fastest-way-of-finding-the-middle-value-of-a-triple

Comment: What do you mean "few tests were made"?  There are 6 possible orders: `a < b < c`, `a < c < b`, `b < a < c`, `b < c < a`, `c < a < b`, `c < b < a`.  If all six of those cases work, your code is fine.

Comment: @ajb exhaustive testing might require a bit more than 6 cases since it is conceivable that e.g. a bug might show up in `a = b < c` but not in `a < b < c` The distinction between `<` and `<=` might be relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way of finding the middle value of a triple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582356/fastest-way-of-finding-the-middle-value-of-a-triple)

Comment: You said "I don't want to calculate the median ... just the one that's in the middle..."  That's pretty much the definition of median.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried three various options and counted time taken by each one of them in the iteration of 1,000,000

1. Using complex ternary
2. Using Collections sort method with List
3. Using Math min and max

All of them give same result but 2 and 3 are executed in almost zero milliseconds

**Performance Test**

```
int iterationCount = 1000000; // 1 million iterations
        Long t1 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterationCount; i++) {
            middle = a <= b ? (c <= a ? a : c <= b ? c : b) : c <= b ? b : c <= a ? c : a;
        }
        Long t2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();


        // #2 Using Collection + List + Sort
        Long t3 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterationCount; i++) {
            List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(a, b, c);
            Collections.sort(list);
            middle = list.get(1);
        }
        Long t4 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

        // #3Using Math's min and max
        Long t5 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterationCount; i++) {
            middle = Math.max(Math.min(a, b), Math.min(Math.max(a, b), c));
        }
        Long t6 = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

        System.out.println("Time Taken #1 -> " + (t2 - t1));
        System.out.println("Time Taken #2 -> " + (t4 - t3));
        System.out.println("Time Taken #3 -> " + (t6 - t5));
```

**Output**

```
Time Taken #1 -> 16
Time Taken #2 -> 71
Time Taken #3 -> 6
```

Looking at the output the option #3 is the best in terms of the performance.

**Best of three**

```
 middle = Math.max(Math.min(a, b), Math.min(Math.max(a, b), c));
```

Comment: Your "benchmarking" measures only 1 iteration of a calculation and includes the call to `System.out.println()`. Fix it and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: better, thanks. Although even 100 is too short. Try 100,000? :-)

Comment: @JasonS tried with 1 million iterations and that actually highlighted the difference :-) thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

> Is this one-liner correct?

Let's step through it:

```
return a <= b ? (c <= a ? a : c <= b ? c : b ) : c <= b ? b : c <= a ? c : a;
```

suppose a <= b. Then if c <= a, return a. Thus, c <= a <= b and a is the correct thing to return. On the other hand, if c <= b, then c <= b < a (b/c we know that c <= a is not true). So, b is appropriate to return.

Now suppose a <= b is false - then b > a. Now if c <= b, we have c <= b < a, so b is correct. If c <= b is false, then we have c > b and b > a so we will return a. Notice that you have an extra comparison. (we already know that b > a, and we've just learned that c > b, which gives us the ordering)

Notice two things about this one-liner: while it turned out that your logic was correct, it was difficult and time-consuming to determine that correctness, and it doesn't scale (imagine this one-liner for five items...)

The correct approach is to sort the list and take the middle item.

(which is exactly what you asked for: "just the one that's in the middle if these 3 were ordered from smallest to greatest.")

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.max(Math.min(a, b), Math.min(Math.max(a, b), c));
```

Works for all cases.

Comment: Doesn't scale though. What about the median of [1, 6, 3, -1, 98, 2, 7]?

Comment: I'm implementing the selection of a pivot for quicksort algorithm. From this POV, not necessary, but very much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, so if you're writing a sort then you're assuming you don't have a sort - if you know that you're dealing with a list of three, always, this is a better answer.

Comment: Yes, at least of three.