# given 5 numbers, what is the minimum number of comparisons needed to find the median?

Tags: algorithm, compare, median, minimum

how do you setup minimum number of comparisons in general?

Comment: See http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12257/exact-number-of-comparisons-to-compute-the-median

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To cite Donald Knuth (by way of Wikipedia, since I don't have my copy of TAOCP at the moment), the lower bound for the number of comparisons is six:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm (scroll down to the section entitled "Lower Bounds").

Your goal is, effectively, to find the k lowest values where k is half the size of the list, rounded up, (so, k = 3; n = 5) and then take the max of those.  Plugging that into the formula there on the page, you get:

```
(5 - 3) + 1 + 1 + 2 = 6
```

In this case, [the actual minimum number of required comparisons is also six](http://tysondw.blogspot.com/2009/09/minimum-number-of-comparisons-to-find.html).

If you're in doubt that the task of finding the median is as hard as finding k lowest values, you may refer to Knuth's TAoCP, volume 3, excercise #2 after 5.3.3 chapter.

Comment: However, it's not obvious that finding N/2 lowest elements would be as hard as finding only one median.

Comment: Once you've found the N/2 smallest elements, the largest of those elements is the median, and since you've just done all of the necessary comparisons, you know which of the N/2 smallest elements is the largest.

Comment: Agreed. 6 is the best you can do .

Comment: Something is wrong with your or my calculation. (5 - 3) + 2 + 3 is my solution. log_2(4) = 2 and ceil(log_2(5) = 3. Need help!

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of material on this in volume 3 of Donald Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*, in section 5.3.3, *Minimum-Comparison Selection*, where the more general question of the minimum number of comparisons required to select the *t*th largest of *n* values is considered. (This value is denoted by *V<sub>t</sub>(n)*).

Knuth gives an upper bound of *n - t + (t-1)⌈lg(n + 2 - t)⌉* for *V<sub>t</sub>(n)*, achieved by first determining the largest element of *n - t + 2* by a tournament system, removing this (since it cannot be the *t*th largest) and replacing it with one of the remaining elements, continuing this procedure until all elements have been a part of this procedure, and then the largest element at this stage is the *t*th largest of the original set. In this case, *n = 5* and *t = 3*, so the upper bound given by this formula is 6 comparisons.

Knuth mentions that this upper bound is exact when *n ≤ 6*, so that applies in this case. In general, my understanding is that there are no general procedures for finding minimum-comparison algorithms for selection (and sorting), and records for increasing values of *n* typically use special tricks that either are not generally applicable to larger values or are simply beaten by other tricks when *n* increases.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer is 6. Here's how.**
*(Originally posted on [How do I calculate the "median of five" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480960/how-do-i-calculate-the-median-of-five-in-c))*

Let's denote these five numbers by *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*, and *e*.

Compare *a* and *b*, *c* and *d*. WLOG let *a* < *b*, *c* < *d*. (2 comparisons so far)

Compare *a* and *c*. WLOG let *a* < *c*. (3)

Compare *b* and *e*. (4) Note that *b* is used instead of *d* (and they cannot be swapped) because *b* is the "counterpart" of the smaller of *a* and *c*.

Case 1: let *b* < *e*.

____Compare *b* and *c* — the greater value is the median. (5)

Case 2: let *b* > *e*.

____Compare *a* and *e*. (5)

____Case 2.1: let *a* < *e*.

________Compare *c* and *e* — the greater value is the median. (6)

____Case 2.2: let *a* > *e*.

________Compare *b* and *c* — the smaller value is the median. (6)

*(Formatting is ugly ik >.<)*