# Standard sorting networks for small values of n

Tags: c, sorting, median, sorting-network

I'm looking for a sorting network implementation of a 5-element sort, but since I couldn't find a good reference on SO, I'd like to ask for sorting networks for all small values of n, at least n=3 through n=6 but higher values would be great too. A good answer should at least list them as sequences of "swap" (sort on 2 elements) operations, but it might also be nice to see the recursive decomposition in terms of lower-order sorting networks.

For my application, I actually only care about the median of 5 elements, not actually putting them in order. That is, the order of the other 4 elements may be unspecified in the result as long as the median ends up in the right place. Can a sorting-networks-related approach be used to compute the median with fewer swaps than performing a full sort? If so, such a solution to my problem (for n=5) and for other cases would make a great answer too.

(Note: I've tagged this question C because C is the language I use and I suspect people who follow the C tag have good answers, but I don't really care if an answer is actually written in C versus pseudo-code as long as it easily translates to C, which it should naturally do as long as the above-mentioned criteria are met.)

Comment: Are the values of the n elements bound or are they arbitrary values?

Comment: They're opaque objects on which the only operations are compare and swap, but since `n` is small, a good implementation would be to use an array of pointers/indices and perform the swaps in the pointer array instead.

Comment: what I think JoshD was getting at, are the values _astronomically_ large, like vales with 10^999 numbers in them? From your answer I guess not, but the question is clever.

Comment: @Amigable: although it's not stated here, sorting networks are formulated in terms of an array, which (at least in C) means that the actual objects being sorted are all of the same size, and hence cannot themselves take arbitrarily many values. If the objects are pointers, then since they're opaque, yes, they could point to something which represents an astronomically large number.

Comment: Here's what I'm using this for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908073/optimal-median-of-medians-selection-3-element-blocks-vs-5-element-blocks - if anyone has thoughts on that I'd appreciate them. I didn't tag it C because the question really has nothing C-specific in it.

Comment: [pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html](http://pages.ripco.net/~jgamble/nw.html) generates Bose-Nelson, Hibbard and Batcher sorting networks for up to 32 inputs. (Careful, the SWAP macros may not be in parallel order.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pick one from each section, presumably whichever runs fastest on your hardware since we're firmly in the realm of "fiendish optimization": http://smarterrecall.com/networks.html , reproduced below:

*I created this site to list all possible optimal sorting networks up to 6-inputs written using a program in matlab. The longest run-time is for 5-inputs at 45 seconds. If you are interested in contacting me, I can be reached at rpl1 [AT] rice [DOT] edu
Cheers,
Richard L.*

```
----------

 - 2-input: 1 network

    [[1 2]]


----------


 - 3-input: 6 networks

[[1 2][1 3][2 3]]
[[1 2][2 3][1 2]]
[[1 3][1 2][2 3]]
[[1 3][2 3][1 2]]
[[2 3][1 2][2 3]]
[[2 3][1 3][1 2]]


----------

 - 4-input: 3 networks

[[1 2][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
[[1 3][2 4][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
[[1 4][2 3][1 2][3 4][2 3]]


----------

 - 5-input: 180 networks

    [[1 2][3 4][1 3][2 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 4][1 3][4 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 4][1 3][4 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 4][1 4][2 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 4][1 4][3 5][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 4][1 5][2 3][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 4][1 5][2 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 4][1 5][2 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 4][2 4][3 5][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 4][2 4][3 5][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][1 3][2 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 5][1 3][4 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][1 3][4 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 5][1 4][2 3][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][1 4][2 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][1 4][2 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 5][1 5][2 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 5][1 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 5][2 5][3 4][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][3 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][4 5][1 3][2 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][4 5][1 3][2 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][4 5][1 4][2 3][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][4 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][4 5][1 4][3 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][4 5][1 4][3 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][4 5][1 5][2 3][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][4 5][1 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][4 5][2 5][3 4][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 2][4 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][1 2][3 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 4][1 2][4 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 4][1 4][2 5][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][1 4][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 4][1 5][2 3][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][1 5][3 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][1 5][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 4][2 5][3 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][2 5][3 4][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 5][1 2][3 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 5][1 2][4 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 5][1 4][2 3][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][1 4][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 5][1 5][2 4][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][1 5][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][2 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][2 4][3 5][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][4 5][1 2][3 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][4 5][1 2][3 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][4 5][1 4][2 3][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][4 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][4 5][1 4][2 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][4 5][1 4][2 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][4 5][1 5][2 3][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][4 5][1 5][2 4][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 3][4 5][2 5][3 4][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 3][1 2][3 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 3][1 2][4 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 3][1 3][2 5][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][1 3][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 3][1 5][2 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][1 5][3 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][1 5][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 3][2 5][3 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][2 5][3 4][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 5][1 2][3 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 5][1 2][3 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 5][1 3][2 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][1 3][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 5][1 5][2 3][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][1 5][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][2 3][4 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][2 5][2 4][3 5][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][3 5][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][3 5][1 2][4 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][3 5][1 3][2 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][3 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][3 5][1 3][2 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][3 5][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][3 5][1 5][2 3][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][3 5][1 5][2 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 4][3 5][2 5][3 4][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 3][1 2][3 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 3][1 2][4 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 3][1 3][2 4][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][1 3][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 3][1 4][2 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][1 4][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 3][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][2 4][3 5][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 3][2 5][3 4][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 4][1 2][3 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 4][1 2][3 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 4][1 3][2 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][1 3][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 4][1 4][2 3][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][1 4][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][2 3][4 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][2 4][2 5][3 4][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][3 4][1 2][3 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][3 4][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][3 4][1 2][4 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][3 4][1 3][2 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][3 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][3 4][1 4][2 3][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][3 4][1 4][2 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][3 4][2 3][4 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[1 5][3 4][2 4][3 5][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 2][3 5][1 4][2 3][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 2][3 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 3][2 4][1 2][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 3][2 4][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 3][2 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 4][2 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 4][3 5][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 5][2 4][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 5][2 4][1 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 3][4 5][1 5][3 4][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][1 3][2 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 2][4 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 3][2 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 3][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 4][2 3][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 4][2 3][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 4][2 5][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 5][2 3][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 5][2 3][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 4][3 5][1 5][3 4][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 2][3 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 2][4 5][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 3][4 5][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 4][2 3][1 2][3 5][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 4][2 3][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 4][3 5][1 2][4 5][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 5][2 3][1 2][3 4][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 5][2 3][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
    [[2 5][3 4][1 5][2 4][1 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][2 3]]


----------


 - 6-input: 90 networks

    [[1 2][3 4][5 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 4][5 6][1 3][2 6][4 5][1 4][2 3][5 6][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 4][5 6][1 4][2 6][3 5][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 4][5 6][1 5][2 3][4 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 4][5 6][1 5][2 4][3 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 4][5 6][1 6][2 4][3 5][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][4 6][1 3][2 4][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][4 6][1 3][2 6][4 5][1 4][2 3][5 6][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][4 6][1 4][2 3][5 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][4 6][1 4][2 5][3 6][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][4 6][1 5][2 6][3 4][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 5][4 6][1 6][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 6][4 5][1 3][2 4][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 6][4 5][1 3][2 5][4 6][1 4][2 3][5 6][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 6][4 5][1 4][2 3][5 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 6][4 5][1 4][2 6][3 5][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 6][4 5][1 5][2 6][3 4][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 2][3 6][4 5][1 6][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][5 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][1 4][2 3][5 6][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][5 6][1 4][2 5][3 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][5 6][1 5][2 3][4 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][5 6][1 5][2 6][3 4][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 4][5 6][1 6][2 5][3 4][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][4 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][1 4][2 3][5 6][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][4 6][1 4][2 3][5 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][4 6][1 4][2 6][3 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][4 6][1 5][2 4][3 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 5][4 6][1 6][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 6][4 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 6][4 5][1 2][3 5][4 6][1 4][2 3][5 6][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 6][4 5][1 4][2 3][5 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 6][4 5][1 4][2 5][3 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 6][4 5][1 5][2 4][3 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 3][2 6][4 5][1 6][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][5 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][1 4][2 3][5 6][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][5 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][5 6][1 5][2 4][3 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][5 6][1 5][2 6][3 4][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 3][5 6][1 6][2 5][3 4][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][3 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][3 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][3 6][1 3][2 4][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][3 6][1 3][2 6][4 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][3 6][1 5][2 3][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 5][3 6][1 6][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 6][3 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 6][3 5][1 2][3 6][4 5][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 6][3 5][1 3][2 4][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 6][3 5][1 3][2 5][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 6][3 5][1 5][2 3][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 4][2 6][3 5][1 6][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][4 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][1 4][2 3][5 6][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][4 6][1 3][2 4][5 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][4 6][1 4][2 5][3 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][4 6][1 4][2 6][3 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 3][4 6][1 6][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][3 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][3 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][3 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][3 6][1 3][2 6][4 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][3 6][1 4][2 3][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 4][3 6][1 6][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 6][3 4][1 2][3 5][4 6][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 6][3 4][1 2][3 6][4 5][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 6][3 4][1 3][2 4][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 6][3 4][1 3][2 5][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 6][3 4][1 4][2 3][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 5][2 6][3 4][1 6][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 3][4 5][1 2][3 5][4 6][1 4][2 3][5 6][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 3][4 5][1 3][2 4][5 6][1 2][3 6][4 5][2 4][3 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 3][4 5][1 4][2 5][3 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 3][4 5][1 4][2 6][3 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 3][4 5][1 5][2 4][3 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][1 3][2 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 4][3 5][1 2][3 6][4 5][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 4][3 5][1 3][2 5][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 4][3 5][1 3][2 6][4 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 4][3 5][1 4][2 3][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 4][3 5][1 5][2 3][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 5][3 4][1 2][3 5][4 6][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 5][3 4][1 2][3 6][4 5][1 3][2 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 4][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 5][3 4][1 3][2 6][4 5][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 5][3 4][1 4][2 3][5 6][1 2][3 5][4 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
    [[1 6][2 5][3 4][1 5][2 3][4 6][1 2][3 4][5 6][2 3][4 5][3 4]]
```

Personally I'd check that the sorting network is correct before using it, rather than taking the word of some random page on the internet. Brute force "only" requires running it against finitely many inputs: "obviously" `n!` inputs is enough, and in fact so is `2**n` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Zero-one_principle).

All of the optimal 5-networks involve "3" in the last swap, so picking the median in fewer swaps isn't quite so easy as all that. It can be done in 6 comparisons, though. There's way more code than you need here, if you can ignore the whining about the question:

[Code to calculate "median of five" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480960/code-to-calculate-median-of-five-in-c)

To pick a median you don't necessarily do *any* swaps, other than perhaps one unconditional swap if you want to preserve all 5 values. A move might be adequate.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I don't know if SO needs a copy-and-paste of it, but it would sure be nice to improve the pagerank of that reference, since it didn't turn up at all in my standard googling. :-(

Comment: Yes, SO needs a copy-and-paste.

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant: +100 to your comment if I could give it. Try the link now... Anyone have a cached copy to paste here?

Comment: @Registered User, make it so.

Comment: note: it is enough to test a sorting network against [`2**n` inputs (sequences of zero and one)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Zero-one_principle)

Answer (score 2):

The asker was specifically interested in a median-of-5 implementation based on sorting networks, so I will address this specific case. A brief review of the literature indicates what optimal solutions look like according to various metrics.

Michael Codish, Luís Cruz-Filipe, Thorsten Ehlers, Mike Müller, and Peter Schneider-Kamp. "Sorting networks: to the end and back again." *Journal of Computer and System Sciences* (2016) in table 1 shows that for *n*=5, the minimal number of compare-swaps is 9, and the minimal depth of the network is 5. As each compare-swap is equivalent to two min/max operations,
the minimal number of min/max operations required is 18.

Lukáŝ Sekanina, "Evolutionary Design Space Exploration for Median Circuits". In: *EvoWorkshops*, March 2004, pp. 240-249, gives the minimal number of min / max operations required for an optimal five-input median-selection network as 10 in table 1.

William Gasarch, Wayne Kelly, and William Pugh. "Finding the i th largest of n for small i, n." *ACM SIGACT News* 27, no. 2 (1996): 88-96, table 1: 
at least 6 comparisons are needed for median-of-5.

In general, sorting networks with the minimal number of operations do **not** reduce to median-selection networks with the minimal number of operations simply by the elimination of redundant operations. But it is possible to find networks that do reduce in optimal fashion for at least some values of *n*. For *n*=5, a brute-force search for such networks is feasible.

The code below shows for four variants of five-input sorting networks comprising nine compare-swap operations or, alternatively, 18 min / max operations. When compiled with `FULL_SORT = 0` these turn into median-selection networks with 10 min/max operations. So according to this metric, both sorting and median selection are optimal.

However, when used as a sorting network, all four variants have a depth of six instead of the minimum of five. Also, when configured as a median-selection network based on comparisons instead of min / max operations, all require seven rather than the minimum of six comparisons.

Example compilation results from Compiler Explorer (godbolt): Using 18 min / max operations for five-input [sort](https://godbolt.org/z/QUQaxP), using 10 min / max operations for five-input [median](https://godbolt.org/z/A74HnG).

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define VARIANT       1
#define USE_MIN_MAX   1
#define FULL_SORT     0

typedef float T;

#if USE_MIN_MAX
#define MIN(a,b) ((T)(fmin(a,b)))
#define MAX(a,b) ((T)(fmax(a,b)))
#define SWAP(i,j) do { T s = MIN(a##i,a##j); T t = MAX(a##i,a##j); a##i = s; a##j = t; } while (0)
#else // USE_MIN_MAX
#define MIN(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (b) : (a))
#define MAX(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define SWAP(i,j) do { if (a##i > a##j) { T temp = a##i; a##i = a##j; a##j = temp; }} while (0)
#endif // USE_MIN_MAX

/* Use sorting/median network to fully or partially sort array of five values
   and return the median value
*/
T network5 (T *a)
{
    // copy to scalars
    T a0, a1, a2, a3, a4;
    a0=a[0];a1=a[1];a2=a[2];a3=a[3];a4=a[4];

#if VARIANT == 1
   SWAP (0, 1);  SWAP (2, 3);
   SWAP (0, 2);  SWAP (1, 3);
   SWAP (2, 1);
   SWAP (1, 4);
   SWAP (1, 2);
   SWAP (0, 1);  SWAP (3, 4);
#elif VARIANT == 2
    SWAP (3, 4);  SWAP (0, 2);
    SWAP (2, 4);  SWAP (0, 3);
    SWAP (2, 3);
    SWAP (1, 2);
    SWAP (0, 1);  SWAP (2, 3);
    SWAP (3, 4);
#elif VARIANT == 3
    SWAP (3, 2);  SWAP (0, 4);
    SWAP (2, 4);  SWAP (0, 3);
    SWAP (2, 3);
    SWAP (1, 2);
    SWAP (0, 1);  SWAP (2, 3);
    SWAP (3, 4);
#elif VARIANT == 4 
    SWAP (2, 4);  SWAP (0, 1);
    SWAP (0, 2);  SWAP (1, 4);
    SWAP (2, 3);
    SWAP (1, 2);
    SWAP (2, 3);  SWAP (0, 1);
    SWAP (3, 4);
#else
#error unsupported VARIANT
#endif

#if FULL_SORT
    // copy back sorted results
    a[0]=a0;a[1]=a1;a[2]=a2;a[3]=a3;a[4]=a4;
#endif
    // return median-of-5
    return a2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment. Prof Falken's answer above can be validated in MATLAB along the following lines: using a bit of find/replacing or regex-fu, write

```
sn{3} = [...
    [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]];...
    [[1,2],[2,3],[1,2]];...
    [[1,3],[1,2],[2,3]];...
    [[1,3],[2,3],[1,2]];...
    [[2,3],[1,2],[2,3]];...
    [[2,3],[1,3],[1,2]];
    ];
```

and similarly for the other values of n, then run

```
for n = 3:6
    test_in = cellfun(@str2num,num2cell(dec2bin(0:(2^n-1),n)));
    for j = 1:size(sn{n},1)
        test_out = test_in;
        for k = 1:2:size(sn{n},2)
            temp1 = test_out(:,sn{n}(j,k));
            temp2 = test_out(:,sn{n}(j,k+1));
            ind = temp2 < temp1;
            test_out(ind,sn{n}(j,k)) = temp2(ind);
            test_out(ind,sn{n}(j,k+1)) = temp1(ind);
        end
    end
    test = cellfun(@issorted,mat2cell(test_out,ones(1,2^n),n));
    assert(all(test),['n = ',num2str(n),' failed test']);   
end
```

The assertions hold for each value of n.