# Manual Sorting of 4 Numbers

Tags: python, sorting, math

I am trying to sort 4 numbers and do it without using any built-in functions.
Here is what I have which works in some cases.

```
#sort numbers

def sort_n(w, x, y, z):
    list = [w, x, y, z]
    while list[3] < list[2]:

        if list[0] > list[1]:
            list[0], list[1] = list[1], list[0]

        if list[1] > list[2]:
            list[1], list[2] = list[2], list[1]

        if list[2] > list[3]:
            list[2], list[3] = list[3], list[2]
    while list[1] < list[2]:

        if list[0] > list[1]:
            list[0], list[1] = list[1], list[0]

        if list[1] > list[2]:
            list[1], list[2] = list[2], list[1]

        if list[2] > list[3]:
            list[2], list[3] = list[3], list[2]

    while list[1] < list[0]:

        if list[0] > list[1]:
            list[0], list[1] = list[1], list[0]

        if list[1] > list[2]:
            list[1], list[2] = list[2], list[1]

        if list[2] > list[3]:
            list[2], list[3] = list[3], list[2]

    print list


sort_n(10, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing this?

Comment: look up bubble sort ...  that is probably the easiest sort to implement ... this is just a mess ....

Comment: If you simply want to sort without directly using any built-in functions I suggest that you look at how some of those functions are implemented.

Comment: You do realize that the `>` operator is calling the _built-in_ `__gt__` method of the integers, right? :|

Comment: Why did you put those `while` loops there? They don't actually help; in fact, they make your code wrong.

Comment: hah user2357 is right ... just get rid of the whiles and do your 3 if statements once and it will be sorted

Answer (score 1):

```
def bubble_sort(a_list):
    changed = True
    while changed:
        changed = False
        for i in range(len(a_list)-1):
            if a_list[i] > a_list[i+1]:
                 changed = True
                 a_list[i],a_list[i+1] = a_list[i+1],a_list[i]
    return a_list
```

I think anyway ...

Comment: Yup. `[4,3,10,1]` -> `[1,3,4,10]`. Test case randomly selected by me. Pseudo.

Comment: But `range` and `len` are built in functions :)

Comment: im pretty sure he meant sort functions

Answer (score 1):

Inplace insertion sort

```
def isort(a, f):
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        for j in range(0, i):
            if f(a[i], a[j]):
                a[j], a[i] = a[i], a[j]
    return a
```

Then you can use it like so

```
>>> isort([2,9,8,3], lambda x, y: x < y) # Ascending order
[2, 3, 8, 9]
>>> isort([2,9,8,3], lambda x, y: x > y) # Descending order
[9, 8, 3, 2]
```

However it does use `len` and `range` which are builtins...

Answer (score 0):

you may be looking for the [optimal sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Optimal_sorting) for 4 numbers.

there are more details (in c) at [Standard sorting networks for small values of n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903086/standard-sorting-networks-for-small-values-of-n) and more basic introduction [here](http://guilherme-pg.com/2012/03/27/Sorting-networks-revisited.html).

unfortunately i can't find a python implementation for the n=4 case.  but the question linked above contains:

```
 - 4-input: 3 networks

[[1 2][3 4][1 3][2 4][2 3]]
[[1 3][2 4][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
[[1 4][2 3][1 2][3 4][2 3]]
```

and if i understand correctly, you can pick any line and then do the comparisons described there.  so taking the first line:

```
if list[1] > list[2]: list[1], list[2] = list[2], list[1]
if list[3] > list[4]: list[3], list[4] = list[4], list[3]
if list[1] > list[3]: list[1], list[3] = list[3], list[1]
if list[2] > list[4]: list[2], list[4] = list[4], list[2]
if list[2] > list[3]: list[2], list[3] = list[3], list[2]
```

but i really need to dash and haven't tested that...