# The best method of sorting 3 values using if-statement

Tags: c++, sorting, if-statement

I've found an exercise in "Programming principles and practice by B. Stroustrup's" that asks to write a program to sort 3 integer values using `if-else` statement.

- I've tried a lot and found myself the swapping method although later on I've found it already done on the internet:

  ```
  int x = 3, y = 5, z = 1;
  if(y < x)
     swap(x, y);
  if(y < z)
     swap(y, z);
  if(y < x)
      swap(x, y);
  ```
- Although it works just fine but that simple line function-call (`swap(A, B)`) has a significant cost behind the curtain: A temporary and Copy:

  ```
   if(y < x){
      auto tmp = x;
      x = y;
      y = tmp;
   }
  ```

As you can see it is called at least 2 times in the worst cases like `5 2 7`.

- I've tried a lot and written down all possible permutations until I've discovered this solution:

1- Declare three integer values, let's say `min`, `mid`, `max`.

2- Set `min` to value of `x`, `max` to `y`'s and `mid` to `z`.

3- `mid` (`z`) initial value has 6 possibilities: 2 correct and 4 wrong:

```
2 7 5 -> mid = 5 correct
7 2 5 -> mid = 5 correct
2 5 7 -> mid = 7 incorrect -> mid has max value
5 2 7 -> mid = 7 incorrect -> mid has max value
5 7 2 -> mid = 2 incorrect -> mid has min value
7 5 2 -> mid = 2 incorrect -> mid has min value
```

- So The first thing we do is to check whether `min` and `max` of `x` and `y` are correct otherwise swap `min` and `max`:

  ```
  if(y < x){
      min = y;
      max = x;
  }
  ```
- Now we have correct `min` and `max`.
- Check whether `z` is (previous value of `mid`) greater than `max` and if so we swap `max` and `mid` (`z`):

  ```
   if(max < z){
       mid = max; // update mid to the previous value of max
       max = z; // update max to the previous value of mid (z)
   }
  ```
- Check whether `z` (previous value of `mid`) is less than `min` and if so we swap `min` and `mid` (`z`):

  ```
  if(z < min){
      mid = min;
      min = z;
  }
  ```
- Now everything works fine. Here is the full example:

  ```
    int main(){

        int x = 2, y = 5, z = 7;
        int min = x, max = y, mid = z; 

        if(y < x){
            min = y;
            max = x;
        }
        if(max < z){ 
            mid = max;
            max = z;
        }
        if(z < min){
            mid = min;
            min = z;
        }

        std::cout << min << ", " << mid << ", " << max << '\n';

    }
  ```
- Is my analysis rational? Is my program efficient? Can we depend on it as the best implementation of sorting three values? Any Tip, comment is highly appreciated.
- Input:

  ```
  2 5 7
  2 7 5
  5 2 7
  5 7 2
  7 2 5
  7 5 2
  ```
- Output:

  ```
  2, 5, 7
  2, 5, 7
  2, 5, 7
  2, 5, 7   
  2, 5, 7
  ```

Comment: The optimal sorting network for input size 3 has depth 3 and number of comparisons 3. So your solution appears to be optimal. (I did not check your code) See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903086/standard-sorting-networks-for-small-values-of-n

Comment: @ypnos The basic code presented before the OP's solution also has depth 3 and number of comparisons 3. I think the OP's goal was to reduce the number of assignments.