# How does one find the median of 5 distinct values with 6 comparisons?

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code to calculate “median of five” in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480960/code-to-calculate-median-of-five-in-c-sharp)

Suppose I have five numbers in a list, say [3,2,1,4,5].

How do I find the median with 6 comparisons?

Comment: Is this homework? It smells like homework. If it is, tag it so.

Comment: No, it isn't. I'm learning algorithms on my own :) I'm on winter break right now.

Comment: Why the specific number of comparisons? I don't know any sorting algorithm with O(n) performance.

Comment: Specific for specifically 5-element list. It's a puzzle.

Comment: Wow, that question did it, thanks! Yeah, I think we can close this question if it overlaps with that question. I just wanted to know how to program it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an optimal sorting network for N=5 which requires 9 comparisons and then prune the unneeded comparisons for outputs 0, 1, 3 and 4. There's an example of this which uses 6 comparisons in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480960/code-to-calculate-median-of-five-in-c-sharp).