# Finding the median of medians of quicksort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, quicksort, median-of-medians

I am working on quick-sort with median of medians algorithm. I normally use the selection-sort to get the median of the subarrays of 5 elements. However, if there are thousands of subarrays, it means that I have to find a median of thousand medians. I think I cannot use the selection-sort to find that median because it is not optimal.

**Question:**

Can anyone suggest me a better way to find that median?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480960/code-to-calculate-median-of-five-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Billiska- I don't think that this question is asking about finding the median of five elements.  Instead, the OP is using the median-of-medians algorithm, which requires finding the median of blocks of size five as a subroutine but is a pretty different algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The median-of-medians algorithm doesn't work by finding the median of each block of size 5 and then running a sorting algorithm on them to find the median.  Instead, you typically would sort each block, take the median of each, then recursively invoke the median-of-medians algorithm on these medians to get a good pivot.  It's very uncommon to see the median-of-medians algorithm used in quicksort, since the constant factor in the O(n) runtime of the median-of-medians algorithm is so large that it tends to noticeably degrade performance.

There are several possible improvements you can try over this original approach.  The simplest way to get a good pivot is just to pick a random element - this leads to Θ(n log n) runtime with very high probability.  If you're not comfortable using randomness, you can try using the [introselect algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), which is a modification of the median-of-medians algorithm that tries to lower the constant factor by guessing an element that might be a good pivot and cutting off the recursion early if one is found.  You could also try writing introsort, which uses quicksort and switches to a different algorithm (usually heapsort) if it appears that the algorithm is degenerating.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought it would be better to use median-of-medians algorithm to optimize the quick-sort.